# How to tackle CORS issues with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, cors, axios

I have my backend running at a subdomain. Everything worked fine when my site ran on http protocol. But as soon as I moved the site to https my POST requests stopped working. Following was the error I got at my console.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend.example.com/api/handle-enquiry/' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

My GET requests are working fine.

Note: I checked my network request headers using firefox's developer tools It shows 404 for preflight OPTIONS request.

I tried putting the following code into my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

RESOLVED: But I am still confused about the solution. I just changed the way of configuring headers. Earlier I placed them in my index.php file of laravel backend. Now I am just configuring them at my .htaccess file. How does it make any difference? What am I missing?

Follows my updated .htaccess configuration

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

need to set it to `always`

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"                   
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
```

taken from: https://serverfault.com/questions/231766/returning-200-ok-in-apache-on-http-options-requests